# Minimum number of bits to represent negative number

Tags: arithmetic, digital-circuits, binary

> Minimum number of bits required to represent $(+32)_{base10}$ and  $(-32)_{base10}$ in signed two's compliment form?

My attempt:

32 = 0100000 ( 1st zero - sign bit as positive)

So to represent +32 we need 7 bits

-32 = 1100000 (1st bit 1 - sign bit as negative)

So to represent -32 we need 7 bits

> But answer is given as 6 bits to store -32 and 7 bits to store +32(positve case i understood, negative in my opinion it should be 7 bits). His reason - one 1 bit enough to represent negative number. I am confused. Please clarify here

Also i have following Questions:-

> Can we say number of bits required to represent a negative number is strictly less than( or less than equal to) number of bits required to represent that corresponding positive number?
>
> how can we generalise minimum number of bits required to represent a given positive and negative number say +N and -N in signed magnitude representation, signed 1's complement notation and signed two's compliment notation.

Comment: Your question is not very clear about the actual range of numbers that should be stored. As it stands, the maximum number of bits to represent only $-32$ and $+32$ is a single bit. I guess this is not what you are asking for. If you want to store any number in that range (inclusively), you'd need 7 bits. (32 (negative values) + 1 (zero) + 32 (positive values)). For a 6-bit solution, you'd have to drop the $+32$.

Comment: sir 0 is a bit, 1 is also a bit. Minimum number of bits required to store +32(0100000) is 7 bits. Right most bit 0 to indicate sign bit. I am asking number of bits required to store -32 in signed two complement form, signed 1 complement form and signed magnitude form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The representations of the numbers as 6-bit two's complement binaries are
\begin{align}
+32_{10} &= 10\,0000_2\\
-32_{10} &= \overline{10\,0000}_2 + 1_2\\
         &= 01\,1111_2 + 1_2\\
         &= 10\,0000_2
\end{align}
which would give the same representation for both numbers. That means you cannot use 6-bits numbers to represent both values using two's complement.

For 7-bit binaries it works, however:
\begin{align}
+32_{10} &= 010\,0000_2\\
-32_{10} &= \overline{010\,0000}_2 + 1_2\\
         &= 101\,1111_2 + 1_2\\
         &= 110\,0000_2
\end{align}
As you can see, the most significant bit represents the sign of the number.

---

Another perspective on your question: What is the biggest positive/smallest negative number you can store in an $n$-bit two's complement binary? Then the answer is $2^{(n-1)}-1$ for the biggest positive and $-2^{(n-1)}$ for the smallest negative number.

That means that a 6-bit binary can hold values $-32, \ldots, 31$ and a 7-bit binary values $-64, \ldots, 63$. The number $-32$ then fits into the range of 6-bit binaries, while $+32$ doesn't. You'd need one more bit for the latter.

Comment: thank you sir, understood it now.

Answer (score 0):

There are 65 values x with -32 <= x <= +32. You cannot represent 65 values in 6 bits. Either you misread the question, or the answer 6 is wrong.

Comment: sir Qn is not wrong. Question is - Minimum number of bits required to represent (+32)base10 and (−32)base10 in signed two's compliment form? This is a question asked in a competetive exam